# Android: textColor = "@android:color/holo_blue_bright" not working

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, textcolor

I am using ActionBarSherlock Library.

In a simple layout i have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shareWhat"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="@string/what_is_the_picture_about_" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shareProduct"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/product_underlined"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sharePrice"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/price_underlined"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shareStore"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/store_underlined"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shareMarket"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/market_underlined"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want the textColor to be blue and there are 3 different values in **@android:color** for blue. I used all the 3, to check which one looks good.

```
1. android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
2. android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
3. android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
```

But i am getting `white colored text` when i am using the 1st two colors. And if i am using the 3rd color, the textView itself is not visible.

is not even showing up.

why is it so?

i am using application theme as

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
```

in my manifest.

Comment: Which os version do you check on?

Comment: I am testing it on a device with API 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those colors are part of the platform and not ActionBarSherlock. They are also [API 14+ only](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html#holo_blue_light).

Comment: fine. what to do if i want to use the blue color used in the ActionBar. The line below the ActionBar.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc perhaps you could hardcode the color instead of referencing it. As for the value of the color it might be `#ff33b5e5` or maybe one of the other colors in his project (https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/library/res/values/abs__colors.xml). Jake, perhaps you can confirm?

Answer (score 1):

the android:textColor property is looking for a color hex string, ie:

```
android:textColor="#0f0"
```

that would make it green. Find the hex value of the color you want it to be, and set it to that